# Python - passing global variable as an argument to imported module

Tags: python, python-module

In order to run a program `playlist.py`, I have a script for a simple test interface, `interface.py`, with the following code:

```
seeds = {}

user_input1 = raw_input("Please pick a seed: track, artist or genre. >> ")

user_input2 = raw_input("which one? >> ")

if user_input1 == 'track':
    seeds['track'] = user_input2
elif user_input1 == 'artist':
    seeds['artist']= user_input2
else:
    seeds['genre'] = user_input2
```

`playlist.py` is located at the same directory as `interface.py`, and I import the former at this point:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from playlist import *
```

In `playlist.py` I have my classes defined, and the argument `seeds` should be passed like so:

```
playlilst.__init__(self, **seeds)
```

but when I run `interface.py`, I get the following error:

`playlist.__init__(self, **seeds)
NameError: global name 'seeds' is not defined`

Is `playlist.py` being imported the right way? what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: We're going to need to see code we can actually run, which actually produces the problem when run.

Comment: there is no need for that. if I insert all `interface.py`code into `playlist.py`, the program runs as desired. so the problem must be in the way both scripts interact.

Comment: well we need to know what happens after you import everything from playlist. If you just want to know how to pass global vars, regardless of how it will or will not solve your acutal problem it is like so: `global seeds; seeds = {} `. But again, what you are describing shouldn't be a problem, so it will be best for us to see your code.

Comment: I see, but `playist.py` is 3.000 lines worth of code. so it looks I'm at a dead end here, as far as solving this problem is concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In playlist.py,

```
from interface import seeds
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to have to import stuff from the interface into the model.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 certainly not an ideal answer, but it was the only one, and it solved the problem. a little sense is better than no sense at all.